# How to Use Async in Navigation Events

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I am wondering abut the difference between

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

and

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

What is the purpose behind using async in the navigation method? Are there advantages,and under what kind of conditions would it be optimal to do this? I have never used async before in a navigation event, but a new tutorial I am referencing is.

Comment: Did you read [`async (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) documentation first?

Comment: Ok I understand. The sample `OnNavigateTo` event is actually using `await InitializeCamera(_sensorLocation);`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx is a really good reference as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you mark the method as **async** you can make asynchronous calls in it, which will not block the UI thread. For example: In the **OnNavigatedTo** method you can load some data asynchronously.
As @Soner Gönül mentioned in the comments, you should look up the [async (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand that for tasks that may take time or block the UI, I should use async method, but I've also seen it used in basic navigation to different pages. My main question is, what should I be looking for in general when determining whether to use async or not.

Comment: @Matthew Well according to MS, anything that takes longer than 20ms(or was it 50..) should be async. So if you have operations that take longer than that in the navigation, it should be async. Another reason why most people use async is that the UI thread should only do UI work and anything else from that should be in a separate thread (async method).